# getting the same ActionEvent to both adding and choosing a item in comboBox java

Tags: java, user-interface, combobox, actionlistener

I have ActionListener to my Jcombobox which needs to add a new row in a table when choosing an item from the comboBox, 
unfortunately, i have also an option to insert a new item to the same comboBox.

my problem is that both action have the same action event "comboBoxChanged"

here some of the code:

```js
cmbAllMovies.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   
 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   
  Movie movie = (Movie) cmbAllMovies.getSelectedItem();
  Object [] rowData= {movie.getName(),movie.getYear(),movie.getlanguage()}; 
  tblModel.addRow(rowData);
 }
});
```

thanks ,

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: Your question is kind of unclear, so the answer is based on my personal guess which is, you do not want the action listener of the combobox to be fired when you add new elements in it.

The solution is to remove the action listener of the combobox the moment you add new element in it and then restore/re-add the action listener.

[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/):

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JComboBox<String> comboBox;

    public Test() {
        super("test");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        String[] movies = { "Rambo 1", "Rocky 1", "Fargo", };
        comboBox = new JComboBox<>(movies);
        comboBox.addActionListener(this);
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
        JButton button = new JButton("Add movie");
        button.addActionListener(e -> {
            String selectedMovie = textField.getText();
            comboBox.removeActionListener(this);// Remove the action listener
            comboBox.addItem(selectedMovie); // Add the movie without any action listener
            comboBox.addActionListener(this); // Restore action listener
        });
        add(comboBox);
        add(textField);
        add(button);
        setSize(300, 300);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new Test().setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(comboBox.getSelectedItem() + " is a great movie.");
    }

}
```